# How do we query nested dictionary in django-hstore?

Tags: python, django, django-hstore

I have this stored in my `serializedDictionaryField`:

```
data = {
    'k1': 'v1',
    'k2': 'v2',
    'k3': {'nested_k': 'nested_v'}
}
```

Is it possible to filter by values of nested dictionary? something like

```
Model.objects.filter(data__contains={'nested_k': 'nested_v'})
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Postgres does not even support nested dictionaries. Keys and values are stored as text. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HStoreField` is just mapping string to string and does not support nested structure, you can use rather `JSONField` which come as built-in Posgres Field in Django 1.9+ and posgres 9.4+.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import JSONField
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, default=dict)
```

**views.py:**

```
MyModel.objects.filter(data__k3__contains={'nested_k': 'nested_v'})
```